# Protected routes for react router v5 isn't working

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, protected

I'm trying to create a protected/private route with react-router-dom v5, as in the link here, I use only the code I needed - [Protected routes and authentication with React Router v5](https://ui.dev/react-router-v5-protected-routes-authentication/).
Now I need both components private from each other 
**The problem**: after Getting `Home` component transferred from`SignUp` components **I can go back to `SignUp` and thats not what I want**.

Signup corrently is the first page (as sign-in). I don't want the user to go back to sigh-up components if he already signed up and present at the `Home` component.

The working website project is here - [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-ishizaka-u27q1)

Anyone has idea how can I make both component protected/private?

**GuardedRoute.jsx**

```js
function GuardedRoute({ children, auth, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() => {
        return auth === true ? children : <Redirect to="/signup" />;
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default GuardedRoute;
```

**App.js**

```js
const App = () => {
  const [userID, setUserID] = useState('');
  const [userSignedUp, setIfSignUp] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App-div">
      <GuardedRoute exact path="/home" auth={userSignedUp}>
        <Home userIDNumber={userID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
      </GuardedRoute>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/signup">
          <SignUp setUserNumber={setUserID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

##### Please try any of your solutions at my codesandbox before posting your answer so we will not try solutions in theory only and in vain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `signup` route only exist if the user is not logged in, and then use a catch-all that will redirect to `/home`

```
<div className="App-div">
  <Switch>
    {!userSignedUp && (
      <Route path="/signup">
        <SignUp setUserNumber={setUserID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
      </Route>
    )}
    <GuardedRoute path="/home" auth={userSignedUp}>
      <Home userIDNumber={userID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
    </GuardedRoute>

    <Route path="/">
      <Redirect to="/home" />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</div>
```

Updated sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-https-t7dmj?file=/src/containers/App.js

---

or you could encapsulate the logic to another component like `GuardedRoute`, let say `UnguardedRoute` that will redirect somewhere if user is logged in.

Comment: Ok Gabriele ty, why is the ```<Route path="/"> <Redirect to="/home" /> </Route>``` needed ? Why it won't work without it ? it's look duplicated code.

Comment: I have added this at the end, so it will catch any path not caught by other rules, and will redirect to home. So if after logging you go to `/signup` the first route will not exist, but the route cannot be handled by any other `Route`. Now it will reach the last one and be redirected to `/home`. If you create an `UnguardedRoute` you do not need this as that component will do the redirecting. But you might want a catch-all for other reasons.

Comment: I have `UnguardedRoute ` its almost as same as my `GuardedRoute` but still without `<Route path="/"><Redirect to="/home" /></Route>` I get only `http://localhost:3002/` which is an empty screen.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, if I'm at  `SignUp`  and I erase the URL like that  - http://localhost:3002 it won't go to `Home`. Why is that ? How is that work ? Thank you Gabriele for your time to explain me.

Comment: @ExtraSun can you post an updated codesandbox so i can have a look ?

Comment: It's your own code that is working but I don't understand how and why, as I wrote in my previous comments above.

Comment: If you are at `localhost:3002` then none of the route `path` you have match. So nothing will be rendered. The `path="/"` route i added at the end will match anything. And since all are in a switch, so only one can match - in order from top to bottom, when no `path` is matched it will reach the one that redirects.

Comment: I don't use the `{!userSignedUp && (` condition. When the `userSignedUp` === fasle, I wondered how it will do the check at `GuardedRoute`  if it first goes to `Redirect to ='/home'`.   I prefer `UnguardedRoute` same as `GuardedRoute`.